# Configured the custom WCF service on Windows Server 2012

Tags: web-services, windows-server

I have windows server 2012 and sharepoint 2013 installed. Now i wanted to configured my wcf service on the server.

After Creating the new app pool & site its shows me the error as below 
**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

The configuration section 'system.serviceModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Also i have found the solution on the link below HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

where suggested to run the command "servicemodelreg -i". I have did the same and my service started working. But i found the sharepoint services are stopped working showing the below error

**Exception message**: 
Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Please help me out to the resolve this problem.....

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when there are multiple versions of the .NET Framework on the computer that is running IIS, and IIS was installed after .NET Framework 4.0 or before the Service Model in Windows Communication Foundation was registered.

To register the correct version of ASP.NET you need type the following command at the commands prompt:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
iisreset
```

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179%28v=nav.70%29.aspx)